# Need help understanding why this value is staying as 1? Python CSV

Tags: python, csv

So this block of code is supposed to open the csv file, get the values from column 1-3 (not 0). Once it has got the values for each row and their 3 columns, it is supposed to add these values up and divide by 3. I thought this code would work however the addition of the 3 columns in each row doesn't seem to be working. If anyone could tell me why and how i can fix this, that would be great, thank you. I'm pretty certain the problem lies at the `for index, summedValue in enumerate (sums):` Specifically, the "summedValue" value.

```
if order ==("average score"):
    askclass = str(input("what class?"))
    if askclass == ('1'):
            with open("Class1.csv") as f:
                columns = f.readline().strip().split(" ")
                sums = [1] * len(columns)

                for line in f:
                    # Skip empty lines
                    if not line.strip():
                         continue

                    values = line.split(" ")
                    for i in range(1,len(values)):
                        sums[i] += int(values[i])

                for index, summedValues in enumerate (sums):    
                  print (columns[index], 1.0 * (summedValues) / 3)
```

Comment: there are indentation issues

Comment: @valentin thanks for commenting, may i ask specifically where?

Comment: @CallumHemsley, add your code exactly as you have it locally. As it is not it would not even run

Comment: @PadraicCunningham this was copied and pasted from my local code.

Comment: the second line would cause a syntax error, make sure your indentation is exactly the same as indentation matters a lot.

Comment: Ah my bad, edited, but this was not the cause of my problem.

Comment: what does your file content look like? I imagine this can be done in a couple of lines using the csv module

Comment: My file is in CSV format, it has names in the first column, and then 3 scores in their individual columns. so for example: Callum,2,6,8 But i have multiply names and scores

Comment: what output do you want from `Callum,2,6,8`?

Comment: I want it to skip the first column, produce the mean average from the 3 scores and output the average.

Comment: is it python2 or 3? Also your data is comma separated yes?

Comment: 3, sorry for not putting in the required detail, i'm new around here and yes it is comma seperated.

Comment: So basically you just want to see the name and their average score?

Comment: Yes please, but just as an output, i do not want it to overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from statistics import mean
import csv

with open("Class1.csv") as f:
    # create reader object
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # skip headers
    headers = next(r)
    # exract name from row and use statistics.mean to average from row[1..
    # mapping scores to ints
    avgs = ((row[0], mean(map(int, row[1:]))) for row in r)
    # unpack name and average and print
    for name, avg in avgs:
        print(name,avg)
```

Unless you have written empty lines to your csv file there won't be any, not sure how the header fits into it but you can use it if necessary.

You can also unpack with the `*` syntax in python 3 which I think is a bit nicer:

```
avgs = ((name, mean(map(int, row))) for name, *row in r)
for name, avg in avgs:
    print(name,avg)
```

To order just sort by the average using reverse=True to sort from highest to lowest:

```
from statistics import mean
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

with open("Class1.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    avgs = sorted(((name, mean(map(int, row))) for name, *row in r),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    for name, avg in avgs:
        print(name,avg)
```

Passing `key=itemgetter(1)` means we sort by the second subelement which is the average in each tuple.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it works great, however it seems to be skipping my first row of results. Thankyou anyway!

Comment: @CallumHemsley, then your file has no header, `headers = next(r)` skips the first row as does `columns = f.readline().strip().split(" ")`, if you don't have a header just remove the next call

Comment: that makes perfect sense, can't describe how grateful i am for this.

Comment: One more thing if possible, i would love it if this was ordered from highest average to lowest. Is this a simple line or code or does this complicate things?

Answer (score 0):

using

```
1, 2, 3
4, 2, 3
4, 5, 3
1, 6, 3
1, 6, 6
6, 2, 3
```

as Class1.csv
and

```
askclass = str(input("what class?"))
if askclass == ('1'):
  with open("Class1.csv") as f:
    columns = f.readline().strip().split(",")
    sums = [1] * len(columns)
    for line in f:
      # Skip empty lines
      if not line.strip():
        continue
      values = line.split(",")
      for i in range(1,len(values)):
        sums[i] += int(values[i])
for index, summedValues in enumerate (sums): 
  print (columns[index], 1.0 * (summedValues) / 3)
```

I obtain the expected result:

```
what class?1
('1', 0.3333333333333333)
(' 2', 7.333333333333333)
(' 3', 6.333333333333333)
```

---

**[update]**  Observations:

1. sums defined ad `sums = [1] * len(columns)` has length columns, but you ignore first column in you operations so value for sum[0] will always be 1, do not seems necessary.
2. for float division it is sufficient `summedValues / 3.0` instead of `1.0 * (summedValues) / 3`

---

Maybe this is what you want

```
for line in f:
    # Skip empty lines
    if not line.strip():
         continue

    values = line.split(" ")
    for i in range(1,len(values)):
        sums[i] += int(values[i])

for index, summedValues in enumerate (sums):    
  print (columns[index], 1.0 * (summedValues) / 3)
```

Comment: i have just copied this into my local code, and has not changed a thing, thankyou for your contribution though. [Update] - I have changed your observation for your second point, but what would i change for your first point?